# PHP why does this only output 1 row?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$responses = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $response = array(
    'name' => $row['name']
    );

    $row;

    $responses['name5'] = $response;
}
echo json_encode($responses);
```

I'm currently only getting 1 rows from this statement I know for a fact their are more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On each iteration of your while loop, you are overwriting the same array key `$responses['name5']`, so in the end you'll only have one value in the `$responses` array.

Instead, you might want something like this to append to the end of the array:

```
$responses[] = $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are overwriting the $response variable that's why, `array_push` instead

Answer (score 1):

$responses['name5'] = $response;

You will get only last row because you replace your data each cycle step.
Try this:
$responses['name5'][] = $response;

Answer (score 0):

Because you're resetting the $response array to a single array in the loop. You want to add to the array.

```
$responses = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($response, array(
    'name' => $row['name']
    ));

    $row;

    $responses['name5'] = $response;
}
echo json_encode($responses);
```

Answer (score 0):

do

```
$responses[] = array('name5' => $response);
```